# Servlet to mysql jdbc connection class not found exception

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, netbeans-8

I am trying to connect servlet to mysql database in netbeans 8 and jdk 8 and glassfish server. i have also included mysqlconnector jar file in libraries but am getting

> class not found exception at Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

piece of my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;

public class sqltest1 extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String user = request.getParameter("user");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo", "root", "root");
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select user,pass from login where user=? and pass=?");
            pst.setString(1, user);
            pst.setString(2, pass);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                out.println("Correct login credentials");
            } 
            else {
                out.println("Incorrect login credentials");
            }
        } 

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reAdding jar file into java **build path** and clean than recompile.

Your code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check mysql driver jar on your classpath and also verify proper mysql driver jar.